# Generating google map url for distance between two variables (town names)

Tags: google-maps, url, maps

I have two variables:

Start
Destinations

I want to enter start and destination in the applicable fields on this site

https://www.google.nl/maps/dir///@53.0845956,6.814237,13z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0

So that the distance between the two locations is visible.

Any suggestions how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directions action of Maps URLs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

For example:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Space+Needle+Seattle+WA&destination=Pike+Place+Market+Seattle+WA&travelmode=bicycling